# javascript for date range validation

Tags: javascript, date

i've a form user can enter any date , but i want to set a date range validation . for example: from 1-12-2012 to 1-1-2013 and the system can't accept any date from user that not in the range.. i've tried this javascript code but it doesn't give me any alert even when date not in range ..

this is part of my form :

```
 echo "<tr><th> Date </th>
  <td> <input type='date' id ='v2' name='v2' value=''   ></td></tr>";


echo "<tr><th> Time </th>
    <td> <input type='time' name='v3' value=''   ></td></tr>";

    echo "<tr><th> Place </th>
<td> <input type='text' name='v4' value=''   ></td></tr>";
```

and this is the javascript code

```
<script language="javascript">

function validation(form)
 {
 var v2 = document.getElementById('v2');
 var date = v2.value;
 if ( v2 > new Date('1/12/2012') && 
    v2 < new Date('1/1/2013')) {
    // date is in your valid range
     return true;
} else {
    // date is not in your valid range
    alert("date is not in the range")
     return false;
}


}

</script>
```

Comment: I don't see how would a browser know it needs to run your JavaScript function for validation. Wishful naming is not enough.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare dates with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the following three lines:

```
var date = v2.value;
 if ( v2 > new Date('1/12/2012') && 
    v2 < new Date('1/1/2013')) {
```

to:

```
var date = new Date(v2.value);
if (date > new Date('1/12/2012') && 
    date < new Date('1/1/2013')) {
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/xGWpW/1/

Comment: Explanation: `v2.value` returns a string representing a date, not a `Date` object, so it needs to be converted. In your original `if` statement you were comparing `v2`, which is the input element, instead of the date.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value of the v2 input field. At the moment your code would not know what v2 is. I would suggest you give an id to the input and use document.getElementById.

```
<td> <input type='date' id= 'v2input' name='v2' value=''   ></td></tr>";
```

Then you can get the value of that and compare it in your script.

```
var v2 = document.getElementById('v2input');
var date = new Date(v2.value);
```

Once you actually have the date value you should be able to compare it.

Comment: i've changed to this .. still same problem

Comment: How are you calling the validate function from your form?

Comment: <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit = "return validation(form); " >

Answer (score 0):

Apart from having to set value of variable "v2", you have to convert it too to the Date object, in order to be able to compare them.